# How should I specify files to read from in my Minitest tests for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In my MiniTest-based tests in Rails, I want to read files that represent dummy data - for example, responses used by `Webmock`, or input from users.

What's the best way to specify the location of these files?

For now, I am using my own helper function that does a `File.join` to reach the `test/fixtures/files` folder, and look for a file there.

Is there a more "conventional" way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed your lead and am also putting my test files in `/test/fixtures/files/*.*`

```
# from test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  self.use_instantiated_fixtures = true


  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

  def read_file name
    filepath = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/#{name}"
    return File.read(filepath)
  end
end
```

Then I call it like this:

```
# from html_import_test.rb
class HtmlImportTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test 'read html' do

    html = read_file 'test.html'
  end  

end
```